# jsp: how to get value from session?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, session

I get an String array from session and I want to show the String from the array.

I know javascript can't get data from session directly. Is there any method I can get the data from session and transfer it to javascrip?

My code as follows:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<%String[] sele = (String[])session.getAttribute("selections");%>;

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
<meta http-equiv="kiben" content="no-cache">
<title>Check List</title>
<script language="javascript"  type="text/JavaScript"  src="cookie.js">
</script>
<script text="text/javascript">
    {
        var selections = //String array form session
        for(var v=0;v<selections.length;v++){
            fillForm(selections[v]);
        }           
    }

        function fillForm(name){
            var checkbox= document.createElement("input");
            checkbox.type="checkbox";
            checkbox.name=name;
            checkbox.value=name;
            checkbox.id=name;

            var label = document.createElement("label");
            label.htmlFor="id";
            label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name));

            var container = document.getElementById("checklist");
            container.appendChild(checkbox);
            container.appendChild(label);
            container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));


        }

          function submitAction(){
              addUserName(document.getElementById("checklist"));
              var elem = document.getElementById("checklist").elements;           
              for(i =0;i<elem.length;i++){
                 elem[i].checked = true;                  
              }
              var form = document.getElementById("checklist");
              form.submit();
          }

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="checklist" action="selection">
    </form>
    <Button type="button" onclick="submitAction()" name="submit">Submit</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't really "pass" variables to javascript so much as print them into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use [JSP Expression Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html) and [JSP JSTL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSTL3.html)

```
<script>
      alert("value:  ${selections}");
</script>
```

Here `selections` is an attribute that is set in any scope page, request, session or application.

You can directly access an attribute form session scope:

```
{sessionScope.selections}
```

---

***Note:*** I don't know that Java `ArrayList` does work in JavaScript as well. If it doesn't work then simply set a comma separated string as session attribute and split it in JavaScript as shown below.

Sample code:

```
<script>
    var selections = "${sessionScope.csv}".split(",");
    for ( var v = 0; v < selections.length; v++) {
        alert(selections[v]);
    }
</script>
```

Here `csv` is a comma separated string value that is set in session scope.

---

*Use JSP JSTL and EL instead of **Scriplet** that is more easy to use and less error prone.*

You can achieve it in JSTL without using JavaScript. Simply iterate the list using `<c:forEach>` tag and add that much of check boxes and labels.

Sample code:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
...
<body>
...
    <c:forEach items="${selections }" var="name">
        <input type="checkbox" name="${name}" value="${name}" id="${name}">
        ...
    </c:forEach>
</body>
```